# How to call a function on selection of date in html5 and bootstrap picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, meteor, mouseevent

I had a html5 input field of type="datetime" which shows a date picker.Now on click of any date  in the date picker,I want to call a function.
If Iam using ng-click ,it is getting called once i click in textfield.Even ng-change is not working.But I want to call the function after selecting the date in datepicker..Which event can be used to achieve this.Can someone help.

```
<input  class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date"
 min-date="{{today}}" min-view="date" maxlength="10" format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
ng-model="$ctrl.DateInput" required="true" ng-change="$ctrl.checkdate()">
```

js

```
$scope.today= new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
this.checkdate=function(){
 alert("hi");
Notification.error('Please select proper date');
};
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `date-time` attribute one of your custom directives?

Comment: no it is not a custom directive

Answer (score 0):

You could watch the variable and than take action on change:

```
$scope.$watch("DateInput", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //..do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the `datetime-local` input type, this is supported by AngularJS, not `datetime`.

Second, the problem comes from the [`input\[datetime-local\]` API of AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D). The ngModel value must be a valid Date object, this is what prevents the ng-change directive from firing.

You could set the DateInput property to a new date using `this.DateInput = new Date()`, however the value displayed will be a complete date string (hours, seconds, ms).
You may try finding a workaroung by applying a kind of filter on ngModel, but it's not natively permitted by Angular and will not be easy.

If you're stuck, you can use the great Angular-UI for Bootstrap library and its [datepicker directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).